# In tx_news, how to set a "detail view" page for news depending on the pagetree

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to set a "detail view" page for news depending on a their storage pid - not on their category - in tx_news in TYPO3 6.x?

Or to automatically assign a category depending on the storage pid?

Comment: The reason behind it is this:

In a site that consists mainly of news, I am thinking about sparing the editors from using categories to catalogize their news and just offering them to add news not in a sysfolder, but on simply on any page. But I still need the "detail view" page for each page, so if you click a news, you will be redirected to the corresponding branch in the pagetree. So this is basically about replacing categories by the pagetree.

Comment: Good question. I remember I was trying to achieve this in the past. If I remeber which project it was I'll try to check its setup.

Comment: Have you tried using TCAdefaults? You can set different values for each sysfolder there, so when creating a new record, the category will be prefilled then. Not tried, so I'm not sure whether this works...

Comment: Nice input, thanks @Michael - I'll try

Comment: Ah but no, then the users can't create new categories / pages as replacement for categories by themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fot tx_news i think the best option is to create your own link-viewhelper and replace the tx_news link-viewhelper-calls in the fluid-templates with yours.
That can extend `Tx_News_ViewHelpers_LinkViewHelper` so you do only have to write the needed code for the pid switch (eg. copy & extend the render function):

`$tsSettings = $this->pluginSettingsService->getSettings();
// <this is new>
if($newsItem->getPid() == 22){
    $tsSettings['detailPid'] = 122;
}
// </this is new>
$this->init();
..`

Comment: I haven't verified it, as I've dropped that use case, but I think this does the job, although you have to "hard wire" the correlation

Comment: Maybe its possible to add custom entries to the news-typoscript-config and use them with ``$tsSettings``

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the markers (replace the link) in a hook:

http://www.mail-archive.com/typo3-german@lists.netfielders.de/msg02305.html

Comment: The answer is about tt_news, the question is about tx_news. I'll make that clearer in the question